# webpack not loading svgs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, webpack

I have the following `app structure`:

```
/webapp
  /lib
    /assets
      ic_add_black_24px.svg
      ic_clear_black_24px.svg
      ..
      ..
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require("webpack"),
    libPath = path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
    wwwPath = path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    pkg = require(path.join(__dirname,'package.json')),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


var config = {
    entry: path.join(libPath, 'index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(wwwPath),
        filename: 'bundle-[hash:6].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'file?name=templates/[name]-[hash:6].html'
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]' // inline base64 URLs for <=10kb images, direct URLs for the rest
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style!css"
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: "style!css!autoprefixer!sass"
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: "ng-annotate?add=true!babel"
        }, {
            test: [/fontawesome-webfont\.svg/, /fontawesome-webfont\.eot/, /fontawesome-webfont\.ttf/, /fontawesome-webfont\.woff/, /fontawesome-webfont\.woff2/],
            loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        // HtmlWebpackPlugin: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles : https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            pkg: pkg,
            template: path.join(libPath, 'index.html')
        }),

        // OccurenceOrderPlugin: Assign the module and chunk ids by occurrence count. : https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurenceorderplugin
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),

        // Deduplication: find duplicate dependencies & prevents duplicate inclusion : https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#deduplication
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

Here is how I am using the `svg asset` in one of my html file:

```
 <md-card-header>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="remove condition" style="background-color: #DCD8D8" ng-click="event.removeCondition(condition)">
                <md-icon md-svg-src="/lib/assets/ic_clear_black_24px.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
        </md-card-header>
```

When I do `rm -rf www/* && webpack -p`, it creates the bundle successfully, but without any assets loaded.. I have tried to use `svg-loader, url-loader, file`, but none of them works.. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is the `src` tag different in the browser?
Also, might help to do a relative path to the svg instead of an absolute path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, I ended up using [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin) to load the assets manually to my required location. This is what my `webpack.config` looks like now:

```
var path = require('path'),
    webpack = require("webpack"),
    libPath = path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
    wwwPath = path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    pkg = require(path.join(__dirname,'package.json')),
    CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin'),
    HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


var config = {
    entry: path.join(libPath, 'index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(wwwPath),
        filename: 'bundle-[hash:6].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'file?name=templates/[name]-[hash:6].html'
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
            loader: 'svg-url-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]' // inline base64 URLs for <=10kb images, direct URLs for the rest
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: "style!css"
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: "style!css!autoprefixer!sass"
        }, {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: "ng-annotate?add=true!babel"
        }, {
            test: [/fontawesome-webfont\.svg/, /fontawesome-webfont\.eot/, /fontawesome-webfont\.ttf/, /fontawesome-webfont\.woff/, /fontawesome-webfont\.woff2/],
            loader: 'file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
                from: 'lib/assets',
                to: wwwPath + '/lib/assets'
            }]),
        // HtmlWebpackPlugin: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles : https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index.html',
            pkg: pkg,
            template: path.join(libPath, 'index.html')
        }),

        // OccurenceOrderPlugin: Assign the module and chunk ids by occurrence count. : https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurenceorderplugin
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),

        // Deduplication: find duplicate dependencies & prevents duplicate inclusion : https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#deduplication
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin()
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```